# Task manager network graph; what's yellow?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

Green: download.
Red: upload.
Yellow: network queue? (download - upload)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Green: Total Transfered
Red: Sent/Uploaded
Yellow: Received/Downloaded

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How have I never noticed these options?

Comment: Because that menu "Network Adapter History" only appears when WTM is showing the Networking tab.

Comment: static-looking menues, that actually change - what a great idea